# asp conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime error SQL aspx

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, datetime, varchar

I don't know what i need to do. I was searching two days and didn't find something helpfull.

```
fieldValue = row.Cells[0].Text;
DateTime timeNow = DateTime.Now;

string constring = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ITCConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(constring)) {
    timeNow = Convert.ToDateTime(timeNow);
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE AktywneZgloszenia SET Data_przyjecia_do_realizacji='" + timeNow + "' WHERE Nr_zgloszenia ='"+fieldValue+"';", connection)) {
        using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd)) {
            connection.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); // <--executeNon
            connection.Close();
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```

When i'm trying to save/update variable timeNow i have an error:

> The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted
>   in an out-of-range value. The statement has been terminated.

Column in both databases type= datetime
variables in dane[] type= string.(not in this fragment)
I cleared all data from database.
What i'm doing wrong ?

Comment: Assuming this is SQL Server, could this be regional settings? E.g. you're trying to store 21/06/2015 instead of 06/21/2015? If you use strings YYYYMMDD is the only safe format.

Comment: Use parameterised queries of the correct datatype.

Comment: i did: DateTime timeNow = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"); - Cannot implicitly convert type'string' to System.DateTime. I tried something like this: DateTime timeNow = DateTime.Now;
                            string format = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
                            format = timeNow.ToString(format); But still the same error like first one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Martin Smith hinted, you want to use SQL Command Parameters rather than build the command via concatenation.

Something like:

```
fieldValue = row.Cells[0].Text;
DateTime timeNow = DateTime.Now;

string constring = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ITCConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(constring)) {
// timeNow = Convert.ToDateTime(timeNow);  (not needed)
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE AktywneZgloszenia SET Data_przyjecia_do_realizacji= @pTimeNow  WHERE Nr_zgloszenia = @pFieldValue;", connection)) {
    using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd)) {
        connection.Open();
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pTimeNow", timeNow); // <-- 'pass' timenow
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pFieldValue", fieldValue); // <-- 'pass' fieldValue
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); // <--executeNon
        connection.Close();
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: The practice of using SQL parameters performs better and protects against t SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Remove this line: `timeNow = Convert.ToDateTime(timeNow);`. It's already DateTime, no need to convert it again.

Comment: Good catch @Zohad Peled - it was from the OP's code and it wasn't relevant to the answer and I totally should have removed it.  Commented above for continuity and clarity.

Comment: yes i added this useless code because i was frustrated :). Thanks you. It's working good right now :)